# get value of checboxes from action

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I have list checkboxes in jsp, now I just want to get value of some checkboxes have checked.

```
    <%
     for(DictItem dictItemDomain : dictItemDomains) {
    %>
    <aui:input 
        name="businessDomains"
        id='<%= "businessDomain" + dictItemDomain.getDictItemId()%>'
        value="<%=dictItemDomain.getItemCode() %>"
        type="checkbox" 
        label="<%=dictItemDomain.getItemName(locale, true)%>"/>
    <%
     }
    %>
```

controller :

```
String[] domains =
        ParamUtil.getParameterValues(
            actionRequest, "businessDomains");
```

but domains contain value of checked and unchecked together

Answer (score 0):

```
<aui:input name="listBussinessDomains" type="hidden" value="" />
<%
for(DictItem dictItemDomain : dictItemDomains) {
%>
    <aui:input 
        name="businessDomains"
        id='<%= "businessDomain" + dictItemDomain.getDictItemId()%>'
        value="<%=dictItemDomain.getItemCode() %>"
        type="checkbox" 
        label="<%=dictItemDomain.getItemName(locale, true)%>"
        cssClass="getval"
    />
<%
}
%>
```

I try to add hidden input and using jquery to make an Array value then I put it for value attr of hidden input, finally, retrieve in action controller.

```
<script>
AUI().ready(function(A) {
    var businessTypeCbs = $(".getval");
    var businessTypeCbsChecked = $(".getval:checked");
    var checkedArr = [];
    var listBussinessDomains = A.one("#<portlet:namespace />listBussinessDomains");

    businessTypeCbsChecked.each(function() {
        checkedArr.push($(this).attr("value"));
        listBussinessDomains.val(checkedArr);
    });

    businessTypeCbs.click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //alert($(this).attr("value") + ' ' + $(this).attr("id"));
            if($.inArray($(this).attr("value"), checkedArr) == -1) {
                checkedArr.push($(this).attr("value"));
            }
        } else {
            if($.inArray($(this).attr("value"), checkedArr) > -1) {
                removeItem = $(this).attr("value");
                checkedArr = $.grep(checkedArr, function(value) {
                      return value != removeItem;
                });
            } 
        }

        listBussinessDomains.val(checkedArr);
    });


});
```

in controller

```
String [] listBussinessDomains = ParamUtil
        .getParameterValues(actionRequest, "listBussinessDomains");
```

WORKED!